# How do I fix "ld: error: unable to find library -lgcc" when cross-compiling rust to android?

Tags: linux, rust, android-ndk, rust-cargo

I'm trying to get rust working on android. However, when I try to cross-compile to android I get the following linking error:

```
$ cargo build --target=arm-linux-androideabi
   Compiling <project> v0.1.0 (<project>)
error: linking with `/opt/android-sdk/ndk/23.0.7599858/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/armv7a-linux-androideabi31-clang` failed: exit status: 1

(very long toolchain command from cargo)

ld: error: unable to find library -lgcc
          clang-12: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I have installed the ndk and changed the linker in `.cargo/config` to the android clang linker. I also tried the standalone toolchains with the same result. The guide I used was the following: https://mozilla.github.io/firefox-browser-architecture/experiments/2017-09-21-rust-on-android.html

Cross-compilation does work when using `crate-type = ["rlib"]` instead of `crate-type = ["cdylib"]`, but I need an `.so` file not an `.rlib` file.

In case it's relevant, i'm using Manjaro Linux.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

UPDATE:

I found the following pull request: https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/85806 After switching to ndk22 it worked. I havn't tried if the pull request fixes the issue (probably does).

Comment: That PR looks like the fix. Are you running a version of rust that's new enough? If that PR wasn't enough, you'll need to file a bug against rust.

Comment: I had to wait until I could mark my own answer as the solution.

Comment: I have the latest Rust, and this problem is happening for me. Switching to r22b also fixed it for me.

Answer (score 5):

Without switching to an older NDK version, I found using the [workaround provided by ssrlive](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/85806#issuecomment-1096266946) to work for me. Here's their comment:

---

> Fixing build error for NDK 23 and above
>
> find out all the 4 folders containing file `libunwind.a`, in my PC,
> it's
> `C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk\23.1.7779620\toolchains\llvm\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\lib64\clang\12.0.8\lib\linux\x86_64\`
> and more. create 4 `text` files named `libgcc.a` in the same folders
> with this contents
>
> `INPUT(-lunwind)`
>
> [image]
>
> [reference
> link](https://github.com/rust-windowing/android-ndk-rs/pull/189/files#diff-9c2f0d812ce52310e2784d3ba203437e6f318230e4e4f701b321a0f656dfa416R180-R187)
>
> In `macOS`, the paths are
>
> ```
> ~/Library/Android/sdk/ndk/24.0.8215888/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/lib64/clang/14.0.1/lib/linux/i386/libunwind.a
> ~/Library/Android/sdk/ndk/24.0.8215888/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/lib64/clang/14.0.1/lib/linux/arm/libunwind.a
> ~/Library/Android/sdk/ndk/24.0.8215888/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/lib64/clang/14.0.1/lib/linux/aarch64/libunwind.a
> ~/Library/Android/sdk/ndk/24.0.8215888/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/lib64/clang/14.0.1/lib/linux/x86_64/libunwind.a
> ```
>
> In `Linux`, the paths are
>
> ```
> ~/Android/Sdk/ndk/24.0.8215888/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/lib64/clang/14.0.1/lib/linux/i386/libunwind.a
> ~/Android/Sdk/ndk/24.0.8215888/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/lib64/clang/14.0.1/lib/linux/aarch64/libunwind.a
> ~/Android/Sdk/ndk/24.0.8215888/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/lib64/clang/14.0.1/lib/linux/x86_64/libunwind.a
> ~/Android/Sdk/ndk/24.0.8215888/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/lib64/clang/14.0.1/lib/linux/arm/libunwind.a
> ```
>
> In `Windows`, the paths are
>
> ```
> ~/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk/24.0.8215888/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/lib64/clang/14.0.1/lib/linux/aarch64/libunwind.a
> ~/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk/24.0.8215888/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/lib64/clang/14.0.1/lib/linux/arm/libunwind.a
> ~/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk/24.0.8215888/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/lib64/clang/14.0.1/lib/linux/i386/libunwind.a
> ~/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk/24.0.8215888/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/lib64/clang/14.0.1/lib/linux/x86_64/libunwind.a
> ```
>
> create file command in Linux/macOS
>
> ```
> cat << EOF > libgcc.a
> INPUT(-lunwind)
> EOF
> ```

---

This is of course extremely brittle and not the "right" solution, but the workaround works fine as of 2022-10-12 with `ndk` version `25.1.8937393`.

Comment: This works for me as well! However be advised that on ndk 25 (and probably above), the files' content should be  `INPUT(-libunwind)`